# Convert the following string to a date

Tags: php

Hi I'm having trouble converting the string:

```
Thu Dec 24 2015 10:39:21 GMT 0000 (GMT)
```

To a date in PHP. I've tried:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$dateTime = strtotime(urldecode($_POST['payment_date'])); //payment_date is the date
$payment_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $dateTime);
```

But it just gives me 0000-12-28 02:39:21[2015-12-24 17:26 Europe/London]

Comment: Use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object [createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = "Thu Dec 24 2015 10:39:21 GMT";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l M G Y H:i:s O', $string);
var_dump($date);
```

**Result:**

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2015-12-24 10:39:21' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 2
  public 'timezone' => string 'GMT' (length=3)
```